# How to exclude "self" in Overpass queries? (when trying to find set of multiple same thing)

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api, overpass-turbo

For example, I want to find all sets of "3 wind turbines within 500 meters of each other in Kanasa". The non-working snippet is:

```
[out:json][timeout:60];
(
  area["name:en"="Kansas"];
);
nwr["generator:source"=wind](area)->.ws;
nwr["generator:source"=wind](around.ws:100)->.ws2;

(.ws; - .ws2;);
out center;
```

which is modified from the [Police station & band example](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_API_by_Example#Banks_far_away_from_police_stations) from the API tutorials, but this approach doesn't work because I'm searching same thing multiple times.